# retrieving corresponding object from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

So the HashMap contains two objects:

```
HashMap<String, String> cust = new HashMap<>();
```

How can I retrieve the second String through the value of the first String?

Let's say the first String represents the name, and the second String represents the address. I want to retrieve the address through the name.

Comment: What is key of your address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you have:

```
cust.put("Jack", "21 Jump Street");
cust.put("Mike", "13 Elm Street");
```

Then retrieve the address of Jack using `get`:

```
System.out.println(cust.get("Jack"));
```